# Approximation to $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n (\ln n)^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, numerical-methods, approximation

How I can find some good approximation to the series:

$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n (\ln n)^2}
$$

The best approximation that I find is 2.056329422629737, but I know it's still a long way off.